# Dynamic Destination Workbook for Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a macro which Copies the Commission Calculation Tables into my Dental Commissions Report. The issue is that I have a fixed name "June Dental Commissions v5.xlsm" in the destination. Is there a way I could replace the "June Dental Commissions v5.xlsm" with a variable which I define as the current workbook in the macro?

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "X:\Customer Service\Dental Reports\Commission Report Calculation\Commission Calculation Tables.xlsx"
Sheets(Array("Entire Commission Table", "Zip & Terr List May 2013", _
    "Abbreviation Finder")).Select
Sheets("Zip & Terr List May 2013").Activate
Sheets(Array("Entire Commission Table", "Zip & Terr List May 2013", _
    "Abbreviation Finder")).Copy Before:=Workbooks( _
    "June Dental Commissions v5.xlsm").Sheets(4)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim wb as Workbook, fName as string, fPath as string

fPath = "X:\Customer Service\Dental Reports\Commission Report Calculation\"
fName = "Commission Calculation Tables.xlsx"

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName)

wb.Sheets(Array("Entire Commission Table", "Zip & Terr List May 2013", _
    "Abbreviation Finder")).Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)
```

Comment: This solution will work if the macro is in the destination file.

Comment: That's how I interpreted "the current workbook in the macro" but I admit it's possible the OP meant something else.

Answer (score 1):

If your macro is not in the active file, use this adaptation of Tim's code

```
Dim wb as Workbook, fName as string, fPath as string, wbDest as workbook

fPath = "X:\Customer Service\Dental Reports\Commission Report Calculation\"
fName = "Commission Calculation Tables.xlsx"

set wbDest=activeworkbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName)

wb.Sheets(Array("Entire Commission Table", "Zip & Terr List May 2013", _
    "Abbreviation Finder")).Copy Before:=wbDest.Sheets(4)

wb.close(false)
```

Comment: are you sure these sheet names exist?